# detecting mobile device through mouse events

Tags: javascript, mobile

I'm looking to detect if a device is a mobile (phone or tablet) or a desktop. I thought of using the `mousemove` or the `mouseenter` event so that when this event triggers, I can set a global boolean flag `IsDesktop` to true.

Is that a good idea or can mouse events also trigger on mobile devices?

Thanks.

Comment: The common way is detected the size of the document, which is the only thing that should bother you.

Comment: Mobile browsers simulate mouse events.  You can instead check for the presence of touch event handler properties. That doesn't really, truly distinguish "mobile" from "non-mobile" however; a 48" touch screen device weight 200 pounds would have touch event handlers.

Comment: @gdoron you're referring to CSS media queries I assume, which is only relevant for styling. For use in javascsript this is pretty useless.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you want to get that information from mouse events? There are so many open source libraries to check that.

Comment: @inhan: I am just looking for a quick and easy way to do without a plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to realize that there are two separate cases here:

1. Display size: large / small
2. Mouse and/or touch

In the 2nd case you don't need to do much else, just implement both sets of events. In the 1st case you might want to load an alternative template; one that is more intuitive for small screen (touch) devices. This is the thing you should be checking for.

There isn't really a way to detect the screen size since pixels are much denser on mobile devices. Looking at the User-Agent string is a good start.

If you're not worried about screen size and don't need separate templates then you don't need to do anything special. Just implement both sets of events.

Comment: The focus of the question is on events, not on screen size.

Answer (score 1):

There is [`sourceCapabilities`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/sourceCapabilities) field in mouse events, which could be used to check if the browser is touch enabled.

Only present in Chromium-based browsers though, experimental, so not recommended for production.